# Hibernate - there is a way of deleting child by id with orphanremoval = true?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to delete a child entity by id in many to one relationship with spring-data-jpa but when I try to look at the child's from the parent perspective its still there but its not in the actual database

the child entity:

```
package com.yoav.todolist.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "task")
    private String task;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Account account;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_of_creation_task")
    private Date date;

    public Task(String task) {
        this.date = new Date();
        this.task = task;
    }

    public Task() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object task) {
        return ((Task)task).getId() == this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", task='" + task + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }

}
```

the parent entity:

```
package com.yoav.todolist.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "account",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Account() {
    }

    public void removeTask(Task task) {
        tasks.remove(task);
        task.setAccount(null);
    }

    public void addTask(Task task) {
        tasks.add(task);
        task.setAccount(this);
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks.forEach(i -> i.setAccount(null));
        this.tasks.clear();

        tasks.forEach(i -> {
            i.setAccount(this);
            addTask(i);
        });
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object account) {
        return ((Account)account).getUsername().equals(this.username);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

the delete by id method: (in the JpaRepository)

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE tasks.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Override
void deleteById(int id);
```

the test(that prove my problem):

```
        Account account = new Account("person", "person");
        account.addTask(new Task("java"));
        account.addTask(new Task("spring"));
        accountDao.add(account);

        MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
        session.setAttribute("isAdmin", true);

        System.out.println(accountDao.findByUsername("person").orElse(new Account()).getTasks());
        assertThat(accountDao.findByUsername("person").orElse(new Account()).getTasks()).hasSize(2);

        mockMvc.
                perform(post("/admin/person").session(session).
                        param(
                                "deleteTask",
                                String.valueOf(accountDao.
                                        findByUsername("person").orElse(new Account()).getTasks().get(0).getId())
                        )).
                andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()).
                andExpect(redirectedUrl("/admin/person"));



        // here is the main problem here I get the both child's
        // account.addTask(new Task("java"));
        // account.addTask(new Task("spring"));
        System.out.println(accountDao.findByUsername("person").orElse(new Account()).getTasks());



        // but here i get only one child and i dont see the child that i removed 
        System.out.println(taskDao.getAll());



        assertThat(accountDao.findByUsername("person").orElse(new Account()).getTasks()).hasSize(1);
```

the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/{usernameOfAccount}", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "deleteTask")
    public String postDeleteTasksOfUsername(
            @RequestParam String deleteTask,
            @PathVariable String usernameOfAccount,
            HttpSession session) {

        if (session.getAttribute("isAdmin") == null) return "unauthorized";
        int idOfDeletingTask = Integer.parseInt(deleteTask);
        taskService.deleteById(idOfDeletingTask);
        return "redirect:/admin/" + usernameOfAccount; // redirecting back to the list of tasks of the specifying username
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// here is the main problem here I get the both child's
// account.addTask(new Task("java"));
// account.addTask(new Task("spring"));
System.out.println(accountDao.findByUsername("person").orElse(new Account()).getTasks());
```

Is your test transactional?

If so, then the `Account` that is being returned here is already loaded into the persistence context, so you're getting the **exact same instance** you got from the previous calls to `accountDao.findByUsername("person")`, which is also **the exact same instance** you persisted using `accountDao.add(account)` earlier on.

Try injecting `EntityManager` into your test and calling `entityManager.flush()` followed by `entityManager.clear()` right after deleting the task.

Comment: but if I am checking it on the UI(in the web app itself) it working and I do not even ```flush``` or ```clear```

Comment: thanks it helps but still its confusing me how its not working on the test but in the UI(the website itself) its working without calling ```flush``` or ```clear```

Comment: That's because in production, the transaction ends right after the corresponding endpoint method is executed, and the persistence context is flushed and then destroyed automatically (upon transaction commit). In your test, on the other hand, the service method behind the endpoint joins the surrounding test transaction. That transaction is still ongoing after the API call